# JavaScript gives error while loading image to img

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to dynamically load images from my project to img elements in a view but when I run the application, it gives me a not found (404) error.

This is the structure of the project:
[please click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gy2ok.png)

And this is the javascript where I am trying to load files:

```
document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("src", "~/files/1.jpg");
document.getElementById("img1").setAttribute("src", "~/files/2.jpg");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Errorname's answer, I tried `..` instead of `.` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`~` isn't recognized as a valid path in html.

You need to provide a valid path (Ex: `./files/1.jpg`)

Comment: I have tried it but doesn't work. it sends the following request: https://localhost:post/ControllerName/files/1.jpg  so it will not obviously find it because it send a call to the controller instead of getting the image. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: I'm gonna need a little more informations about this. Is there an error in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please put the full image , showing the location of your html page also. Assuming your html page is in a different folder but under "wwwroot" then you need to use '../files/imagename'. because '..' will take you to root and then you will traverse through.